# How to add integer and float using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, integer

I am using the below code to add integer and float value using JavaScript. But I can't do this, it returns `NaN`. I am new to development. Please help me to solve this.

```
lbl_bal_total.value = Numbers(lbl_bal_total.innerHTML) + Numbers(lbl_bal_others.value);
//lbl_bal_total.value = 1568 + .25; // Error lbl_bal_total value is NaN
lbl_bal_total.innerHTML = Math.round(lbl_bal_total.value);
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? What is `Numbers`?

Comment: Also the Number() function will return NAN if the arguments value cannot be converted to a number.  Are you sure lbl_bal_total.innerHTML is always numerical characters.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lbl_bal_total.innerHTML = Math.round(parseFloat(lbl_bal_total.innerHTML) + parseFloat(lbl_bal_others.value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Data type is `Number` not `Numbers`

```
 lbl_bal_total.value = Number(lbl_bal_total.innerHTML) + Number(lbl_bal_others.value);
    //lbl_bal_total.value = 1568 + .25; // Error lbl_bal_total value is NaN
    lbl_bal_total.innerHTML = Math.round(lbl_bal_total.value);
```

if you are not sure about the values of `lbl_bal_total.innerHTML` and `lbl_bal_others.value` then you can check it using [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = parseFloat(lbl_bal_total.innerHTML) + parseFloat(lbl_bal_others.value);
lbl_bal_total.innerHTML = Math.round(num);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lbl_bal_total.value = parseFloat(lbl_bal_total.innerHTML) + parseFloat(lbl_bal_others.value);
//lbl_bal_total.value = 1568 + .25; // Error lbl_bal_total value is NaN
lbl_bal_total.innerHTML = parseFloat(lbl_bal_total.value);
```